# How can I make go Time compatible with js Date

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

When I define time like this in js

```
{expiry:new Date()}
```

and create a struct in go endpoints like this

```
{Expiry time.Time `json:"expiry"`}
```

I get a parse error from go

```
"parsing time \"\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"\" as \"\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"\": cannot parse \"07:00\"\" as \"\"\""
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20476078/683201

Comment: ok, that would be a go solution, what about a js solution to reformat time string so endpoints accept?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for time.UnmarshalJSON states:

> UnmarshalJSON implements the json.Unmarshaler interface. The time is expected to be a quoted string in RFC 3339 format.

There is a problem that all browsers doesn't necessarily encode `DateTime` objects into RFC3339 format. However, your error message doesn't seem to imply that. You seem to try to encode the following JSON string:

```
"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
```

That is not a timestamp, but rather the `time` package's reference layout. See this Playground example that shows how Go expects a timestamp to be like: http://play.golang.org/p/4NQ1pRidPt

However, there is still that problem with browser inconsistency. To avoid this you can use a function or library, as @elithrar suggested:

```
var a = {expiry: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")};
console.log(a);
```

**Output:**

```
{"expiry": "2014-01-08T08:54:44+01:00"}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6KE4/3/)

Comment: Why did google chrome decide to do something different then RFC3339? (new Date()).toJSON(); Same company and they still can't tell the time to each other :)

Comment: @GertCuykens Chrome actually works fine for me. `(new Date()).toJSON();` returns `"2014-01-08T15:31:18.683Z"` which follows RFC3339. `Z` is fine. It is `Z07:00` that is invalid.

Comment: hmm where the hell did I at 07:00 in my code then haha :) thanks

Comment: ps can you add this to your answer `{expiry:new Date().toJSON()}` works also for me it was the `{expiry:new Date()}` that did not