# Parsing JSON Time error

Tags: python, json, go, timestamp

I am trying to parse a timestamp that is generated in python and posted over to here to be stored in cassandra and I am getting a weird error.

```
parsing time ""2015-11-05 14:14:32-0700"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse " 14:14:32-0700"" as "T"
```

I don't want to modify the time given to me from the python in anyway, just want to pass it right into cassandra but the driver says I need to have it be `time.Time` (not string) to do so.

Here is the code

```
type OurCustomType struct {
    TimeStamp   time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
}


func extractJsonBody(r *http.Request) []byte {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(r.Body, 1048576))
    if err != nil {
        //...
    }
    if err := r.Body.Close(); err != nil {
         //....
    }
    return body
}

func View(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var variable OurCustomType

    body := extractJsonBody(r)

    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &variable); err != nil {
        //..
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I have implemented my own `time.Time` type and implemented a custom `UnmarshalJSON` to attempt to fix this issue.

```
type PythonTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (self *PythonTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    self.Time, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700", string(b))
    return
}
```

But I am not getting this error:

```
parsing time ""2015-11-05 14:14:32-0700"" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700": cannot parse ""2015-11-05 14:14:32-0700"" as "2006"
```

Comment: The time class requires a format string, in your case it would be `2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700`. I believe you can't supply that to the unmashaller directly so you have to implement `UnmarshalJSON` for your type to deal with it there or unmarshal into a string and convert it later. More on the format string stuff here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845172/parsing-date-string-in-golang and here's an example implement MarshalJSON, what you'll need to do is similar, just for unmarshalling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475321/override-the-layout-used-by-json-marshal-to-format-time-time

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Thanks for the comment, this has gotten me really close but I am still getting an error I am unsure about. See most recent edit

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you on that one. I did a quick test here https://play.golang.org/p/fZ7soeHJhj and it should work. I generally suggest printing/inspecting the value of `string(b)` here cause the formats aren't matching for some reason however the error makes it seem like `string(b)` is producing the expected value.

Comment: Ok I got it working, but I needed to modify the library I was using to do so. I don't think that is right and should be able to make them think my struct IS a `time.Time` type. Is that possible?

Comment: If you define `UnmarshalJSON` for the other type ( `OurCustomType` ) then you wouldn't need that `PythonTime` wrapper you could also declare it like `type PythonTime time.Time` so you're type is an alias for `time.Time` rather than a wrapper around it.

Comment: The last error you are getting is due to the presence of the `"` marks in the beggining and in the end of byte array that represents your time. Since you are reading directly from the json structure you need to trim the `"` to have a valid time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you've got quotations in the date being passed from Python.

In the first error that you posted, you can see that it failed at reading `"T"`. That's because you were using a different format in Go than you were returning from Python.

```
parsing time ""2015-11-05 14:14:32-0700"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse " 14:14:32-0700"" as "T"
```

You used `""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00""` when the format from Python is `""2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700""`.

The same is true in your last error, except that you dropped the one pair of the quotations in the date format verses what you have returned in Python.

```
parsing time ""2015-11-05 14:14:32-0700"" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700": cannot parse ""2015-11-05 14:14:32-0700"" as "2006"
```

This is saying that you provided `"2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700"` but it's expecting `""2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700""` due to the extra quotes in the date returned by Python.